# Is there a Maven repository for Spring 4?

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-4

I'm looking for Spring 4.0 M1, for use with Java 8. According to [this](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-10292?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel) issue there should be a build, can't find however. Ideally there would be a Maven repo, but I can't even find a regular download?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of **December 12, 2013**, Spring `4.0.0.RELEASE` is in Maven Central.

You can add this to your `pom.xml` to bring it in:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 8):

Quoting Paul Grays answer - `Spring 4` is already in Maven central so you just need to add this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**Older asnwer**

I think you need to add Spring repository to your `pom.xml`

```
<repository>
    <id>com.springsource.repository.maven.snapshot</id>
    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/snapshot/</url>
    <snapshots>
       <enabled>true</enabled>
    </snapshots>
</repository>
```

Then you can add your Spring module with following version `4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT`. So for example

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks that's it! Btw, the version is incorrect, it should be 4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT. Can't edit myself cause SO doesn't permit changes < 6 chars.

Answer (score 3):

It is now released, so it can be found in standard repo:
http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.springframework%7Cspring-framework-bom%7C4.0.0.RELEASE%7Cpom

Answer (score 2):

When I look at the Spring Framework [summary page](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR) it states that 4.0 M1 is not released yet - it is scheduled for Tuesday, 2013-05-14

Comment: Indeed, missed that. However it should be possible to download 4.0.0-SNAPSHOT builds if read my linked issue correctly. Any idea where I could find those?